# How do I step into my code (not the test code) using Codeception in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, unit-testing, debugging, phpstorm, codeception

I'm running some unit tests with Codeception. Specifically, I'm testing an API and one of the test steps is failing. I know which step it is but can't figure out why so I want to step into my code as it's being executed by the unit test.

I've tried setting "Break at first line in php scripts", I've debugged the test itself, I've tried writing to the console but there's a lot to narrow down. Is there a way to step into my code like I was debugging normally?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with codeception, but it's simulating requests? When I'm debugging my API using something else it usually works to add `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM` to the query string, you could try put that in your requests from the tests.

Comment: The method called into from my unit test is `sendPOST(...)` which I can add parameters to. I'll add that parameter and see what happens. If not, I can test the same thing in Postman and see how I get on.

Comment: That worked like a charm. Please add as an answer so I can mark you correct.

Comment: Well ... `xdebug.remote_autostart = 1` in php.ini and xdebug will attempt to debug every single request (not ideal because of that but good in case if you do not wish to edit your code). If editing the code is fine -- just place `xdebug_break();` -- programmatic breakpoint. The only requirements from IDE side -- 1) have "phone handle" icon active (so IDE listens for incoming debug requests) and 2) if you are trying to debug more than request at a time (e.g. subrequest) then ensure that you allow more than 1 (by default) simultaneous debug session in IDE.

Comment: I was wondering if it was possible to have a programmatic breakpoint. I'm a C# developer converted to php and all the stuff I take for granted with C# is generally unavailable in php... Glad this one isn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When debugging an API where the request is coming from an external source (not starting a process from within PhpStorm) you can always add `?XDEBUG_SESSION_START=PHPSTORM` to the query string which should start the debugger.

If it doesn't work set it to start at first line of the script and step through. If it doesn't work with the query string it's most often it's because I don't have the correct path mappings set up which you can do from the Settings > Servers.

For anyone else looking at this, as @Brandon mentioned in the comments the first thing you should be sure of is that you have xdebug installed and configured.

Comment: The other note here is to make sure you also have XDebug installed and configured

Comment: thanks, added that for anyone else with the same problem.